# Maximal Unit interval graph construction

Tags: graph-theory, interval-graphs

Is it possible to construct a unit interval graph with $n$ vertices and clique number $k$ such that any other unit interval graph with same number of vertices and clique number is a sub-graph of that graph or isomorphic to a sub-graph of that graph?

My construction for k=3 is,
[image: Unit interval graph for n=8 and k=3]
However, i could not generalize my proof. Please help.

Comment: The graph is simply the $(k-1)$th power of the path on $n$ vertices, $P_n^{k-1}$.